# Running a script just before installation of Debian finishes using preseed

Tags: linux, debian, initrd

I am trying to run a script just before the installation of Debian Wheezy finishes. I am aware of "d-i preseed/late-command", viz. used run commands before the installation finishes. But I am facing a problem. I cannot figure out where to copy my script in the iso file. I tried following two approaches:

1. I tried to copy my script inside the root directory of initrd.gz
   (/install.386/initrd.gz) file and did the following changes in
   preseed.cfg: `d-i preseed/late-command in-target sh /my_script.sh`
2. I also tried to copy my script in the root directory of the iso
   file and did the following changes in preseed.cfg: `d-i
   preseed/late-command in-target sh /media/cdrom/my_script.sh`

So, where to copy a file (here in my script) so that I can use it in late-command?

Comment: Want to know this.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is based on the fact that you use a USB to install the OS, and that you will have in the root of the USB a folder called `files` where you will have the file `preseed.cfg` and an executable called `run.sh`.

This command will copy the file `run.sh` to the root of the user **root** and there it will execute the script.

`d-i preseed/late_command string cp /cdrom/files/run.sh /target/root/; chmod +x /target/root/run.sh; in-target /bin/bash /root/run.sh`

After this you can use `rm` to delete the file. You can also run the script directly from the USB (without copying it), but after some tests I have verified that it can induce human errors