# Run script after Debian installation is complete

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, installation, debian

I am using **preseed** to auto install debian.
I want to be able to run a script called "run.sh" at the end of the Debian installation:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch /root/example.txt
echo $(hostname -I | cut -d"." -f 4) > /root/example.txt
```

I have tried several models that I have found by google (I add these commands to preseed.cfg):

`d-i late_command string cp -a /cdrom/preseed/run.sh /target/root; chmod 777 /root/run.sh; /root/run.sh;`

```
d-i preseed/late_command string \
  in-target cp run.sh /root/ && in-target chmod 755 /root/run.sh \
  cd /target; \
  chmod +x ./run.sh; \
  chroot ./ ./run.sh;
```

I have tried everything I have seen and it has occurred to me, on none of the occasions have I been successful. The most I have achieved is a red screen with an error that the file "run.sh" is corrupt

[I just saw a similar question from 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798376/running-a-script-just-before-installation-of-debian-finishes-using-preseed)

### UPDATE:

These commands work

```
d-i preseed/late_command string mkdir -p /target/root/one

d-i preseed/late_command string cp /cdrom/files/jitsi/run.sh /target/root/; chmod +x /target/root/run.sh;
```

Comment: I haven't tried anything the like before, so can't verify that my assumptions are correct; but to me the `in-target cp run.sh /root/` makes no sense, because it assumes that the *run.sh* already exists somewhere in the target environment.  Have you tried `cp run.sh /target/root/` and `chmod 755 /target/root/run.sh` (without **in-target**)?

Comment: In theory it should be the same as `d-i late_command string cp -a /cdrom/preseed/run.sh /target/root` and yes, I have tried it. On Ubuntu it works, but on Debian it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely the reason that it does not work when trying to execute is because the route has not been declared. You can use this failing that:

`d-i preseed/late_command string cp /cdrom/files/jitsi/run.sh /target/root/; chmod +x /target/root/run.sh; in-target /bin/bash /root/run.sh`